# Fetch data from a Website into an Excel file with the hyperlinks in it

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, excel

When I fetch data from a webpage to an Excel file using Macro it saves the data in the Excel file as it is supposed to be. My requirement is that it should save the data in the Excel with the hyperlinks in the webpage and If we click any hyperlink in the Excel it should go to the particular website and fetch the data and save the information in the excel file or sheet. 
I hope it makes sense. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My Macro code below:

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "website link"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .user.Value = "UserNmae
    .Password.Value = "password"
    .submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "final webpage link"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("AutoNumber1")

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Select
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
    Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close 'er up
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Two immediate problems with your objective.  Excel will only display the first 1,000 or so characters of a cell.  Excel hyperlinks only operate at the level of the cell.

Comment: Ok so assuming you have the hyperlink in the cell, test the cell contents on click for a url/hyperlink and if so navigate then do the similar method above.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this code to get all Hyperlinks from the web browser , i think you can easily export data from listbox to excel

```
Dim links As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Links
        For Each link As HtmlElement In links
            ListBox1.Items.Add(link.GetAttribute("href"))
        Next
```

[Source](http://ultimateprogrammingtutorials.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-get-all-links-of-website-using.html)